# Binding delay one step

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

Ok, lets see if I can explain this well enough in english. This is gonna be long, sorry, be patience, please, I don't know how to make it shorter.

I have two entities as `UserControl`s children of a canvas, whose have thumbs as children of the respective `UserControl`s. I have a polyline connecting those entities through the thumbs, the polyline is child of the same canvas.

The thumbs have a dependency property called `AnchorPoint` (the center of the thumb), the start and end points of the polyline are binded to that property by respective `Start` and `End` dependency properties.

When I move an entity I update the `AnchorPoint` property programmatically to the desired point (the center of the thumb location), the binding change the line points properties, and when the property changes I call `InvalidateMeasure` on the polyline. Therefore the line moves with the entities.

And the code (I'm omitting irrelevant code):

The connecting thumb, child of the `UserControl`s:

```
public partial class EntityConnectingThumb : UserControl, IChartEntityConnectingThumb, IObjectWithCancellableAction, IChartObjectCanBeRemoved, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    internal List<LineConnection> _LinesStarts = new List<LineConnection>();
    internal List<LineConnection> _LinesEnds = new List<LineConnection>();

    public Point AnchorPoint
    {
        get { return (Point)GetValue(AnchorPointProperty); }
        private set { SetValue(AnchorPointProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty AnchorPointProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("AnchorPoint", typeof(Point), typeof(EntityConnectingThumb), new PropertyMetadata(default(Point)));

    private void UpdateAnchorPoint()
    {
        if(_LinesStarts.Count > 0 || _LinesEnds.Count > 0)
            Console.WriteLine("Update anchor point");

        Size size = RenderSize;
        Point ofs = new Point(size.Width / 2, size.Height / 2);

        if (_LinesStarts.Count > 0 || _LinesEnds.Count > 0)
            Console.WriteLine($"ofs = {ofs} {Environment.NewLine}Pre anchorpoint = {this.TranslatePoint(ofs, ChartCustomControl.Instance.ChartCanvas)}");

        AnchorPoint = this.TranslatePoint(ofs, ChartCustomControl.Instance.ChartCanvas); 

        if (_LinesStarts.Count > 0 || _LinesEnds.Count > 0)
            Console.WriteLine($"AnchorPoint= {AnchorPoint}");
    }
    public void MyBorderMovedTo()
    {
        if (_LinesStarts.Count > 0 || _LinesEnds.Count > 0)
            Console.WriteLine("My border moved to");
        UpdateAnchorPoint();
    }
}
```

The lines class, children of Canvas (`aChartArrowLineBase` implements `Shape`):

```
public class LineConnection : aChartArrowLineBase, IChartObjectCanBeRemoved, IChartHaveHiddableThumbs
{
    public ObservableCollection<aLineSegmentBase> Segments
    {
        get { return (ObservableCollection<aLineSegmentBase>)GetValue(SegmentsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SegmentsProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SegmentsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Segments", typeof(ObservableCollection<aLineSegmentBase>), typeof(LineConnection), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
            null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsMeasure, SegmentsPropertyChanged));

    public new void InvalidateMeasure()
    {
        base.InvalidateMeasure();
        _HitboxPolyLine.InvalidateMeasure();
    }
    /// <summary>
    ///     Gets a value that represents the Geometry of the ArrowPolyline.
    /// </summary>
    protected override Geometry DefiningGeometry
    {
        get
        {
            // Clear out the PathGeometry.
            _Pathgeo.Figures.Clear();
            _PathfigLine.Segments.Clear();
            _HitboxPolyLine.Points.Clear();

            // Try to avoid unnecessary indexing exceptions.
            if (Segments.Count > 0)
            {
                // Define a PathFigure containing the points.
                _PathfigLine.StartPoint = Segments[0].Start;
                _PolysegLine.Points.Clear();

                for (int i = 0; i < Segments.Count; i++)
                {
                    var current = Segments[i];
                    switch(current._Type)
                    {
                        case LineSegmentTypesEnum.Start:
                        case LineSegmentTypesEnum.Normal:
                            _PolysegLine.Points.Add(current.Start);
                            _HitboxPolyLine.Points.Add(current.Start);
                            break;
                        case LineSegmentTypesEnum.Unique:
                        case LineSegmentTypesEnum.End:
                            _PolysegLine.Points.Add(current.Start);
                            _PolysegLine.Points.Add(current.End);
                            _HitboxPolyLine.Points.Add(current.Start);
                            _HitboxPolyLine.Points.Add(current.End);
                            break;
                    }
                }

                _PathfigLine.Segments.Add(_PolysegLine);
                _Pathgeo.Figures.Add(_PathfigLine);
            }

            // Call the base property to add arrows on the ends.
            return base.DefiningGeometry;
        }
    }
}
```

The segment base class, children of `LineConnection`, here are `Start` and `End` properties:

```
public abstract class aLineSegmentBase : FrameworkElement, IChartHaveHiddableThumbs, ILineSegmentBase
{
    public aLineSegmentBase(LineSegmentTypesEnum Type, LineConnection connection, EntityConnectingThumb start, EntityConnectingThumb end)
    {
        Start = start.AnchorPoint;
        End = end.AnchorPoint;
        var b = new Binding()
        {
            Source = start,
            Path = new PropertyPath(EntityConnectingThumb.AnchorPointProperty),
            Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay,
            UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged
        };
        SetBinding(StartProperty, b);
        b = new Binding()
        {
            Source = end,
            Path = new PropertyPath(EntityConnectingThumb.AnchorPointProperty),
            Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay,
            UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged
        };
        SetBinding(EndProperty, b);
        _Loaded = true;
    }
    public Point Start
    {
        get { return (Point)GetValue(StartProperty); }
        set { SetValue(StartProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty StartProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Start", typeof(Point), typeof(aLineSegmentBase), new PropertyMetadata(default(Point), OnPointPropChanged));
    public Point End
    {
        get { return (Point)GetValue(EndProperty); }
        set { SetValue(EndProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty EndProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("End", typeof(Point), typeof(aLineSegmentBase), new PropertyMetadata(default(Point), OnPointPropChanged));
    private static void OnPointPropChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ((aLineSegmentBase)d).OnPointChanged();
    }
    private void OnPointChanged()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Line start changed= {p}");
        if (!_Loaded)
            return;
        _Connection.InvalidateMeasure();
    }
}
```

As you can see, `DefiningGeometry` iterates through segments building the polyline with the `Start` and `End` properties, which are linked to the thumbs anchor point through bindings.

When the anchor point changes, the line points changes, and `InvalidateMeasure` is called on the line, which redraw.

When I move the `UserControls` I call every thumbs `UpdateAnchorPoint` method and all works perfect, the line move without problems:

```
private void MovingThumb_PreviewMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        //Calculating new point p ...

        Canvas.SetLeft(this, p.X - _MovingThumbPositionWhenClickedRelativeToCanvas.X);
        Canvas.SetTop(this, p.Y - _MovingThumbPositionWhenClickedRelativeToCanvas.Y);

        UpdateAnchorPoint();
        CalculateSnapCoords(); //Here all thumb's UpdateAnchorPoint methods are called

        ///other stuff...

        e.Handled = true;
    }
internal void CalculateSnapCoords()
    {
        //Doing snap stuff...

        DoActionAllConnectingThumbs(x => x.MyBorderMovedTo());

        //More snap stuff...
    }
```

But now I'm implementing undo/redo stuff, and for that I use this method to move the `UserControl`s to their previous (undo) location or next (redo) location:

```
internal void AutomaticMoveTo(Point p)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Automatic move to = {p}");
        Canvas.SetLeft(this, p.X);
        Canvas.SetTop(this, p.Y);
        UpdateAnchorPoint();
        CalculateSnapCoords();
    }
```

Now comes the problem: that works with the entities, but the lines are updated with "one step of delay", I explain:

1.- I press undo button, the entity moves to the previous location, the line doesn't react at all.

2.- I press redo button, the entity moves correctly, but the line move to the location it should have moved on 1.-

3.- Undo button again, entity moves correctly, line moves to 2.- location.

... and so on.

So, the binding are delayed by one step... ??? Honestly I'm an amateur, but I didn't even know this was even possible.

I'm confused with this, it seems to me that the binding reach the target BEFORE the value has changed, so the new value is not passed to the target. Therefore, when the next step occurs, the target take the old value instead of the new value, and the new value are stored in the property without being passed to the target.

Reading the console output it seems that's exactly what's happening:

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------Last message moving entity
My border moved to
Update anchor point
ofs = 7,5;5 
Pre anchorpoint = 660,80198019802;464,212871287129
AnchorPoint= 660,80198019802;464,212871287129
* Creating undo/redo command:_UndoMovingCoordinates = 609,39603960396;118,594059405941
  ;  Last coordinates = 643,30198019802;442,212871287129
//---------------------------------------------------------------Here start undo/redo
*** UNDO move to = 609,39603960396;118,594059405941
Automatic move to = 609,39603960396;118,594059405941
My border moved to
Update anchor point
ofs = 7,5;5 
Pre anchorpoint = 660,80198019802;464,212871287129
//---------------------------------------------------------------Here lacks a line, see below
AnchorPoint= 660,80198019802;464,212871287129
*** REDO move to = 643,30198019802;442,212871287129
Automatic move to = 643,30198019802;442,212871287129
My border moved to
Update anchor point
ofs = 7,5;5 
Pre anchorpoint = 626,89603960396;140,594059405941
Line start changed= 626,89603960396;140,594059405941
AnchorPoint= 626,89603960396;140,594059405941
*** UNDO move to = 609,39603960396;118,594059405941
Automatic move to = 609,39603960396;118,594059405941
My border moved to
Update anchor point
ofs = 7,5;5 
Pre anchorpoint = 660,80198019802;464,212871287129
Line start changed= 660,80198019802;464,212871287129
AnchorPoint= 660,80198019802;464,212871287129
```

You can see the line `Line start changed=` doesn't appear in the first undo message: the first undo changes doesn't update `Start` property (or at least the property changed event is not being launched). It keeps that delay of one step the rest of the time.

I've tried using `UpdateSource` and `UpdateTarget` on the `Start` and `End` properties bindings, and using `PropertyChanged` on `AnchorPoint` property, but nothing changes.

I can not either bind the `AnchorPoint` property directly to the connecting thumb `Canvas.LeftProperty` and `Canvas.TopProperty` since the connecting thumbs are not children of the canvas, they are children of the `UserControl`.

I have no idea what's happening. Thoughts, hints, something, all are welcome.

Comment: You may want to distill (make it smaller) this issue into its basic problem in a side project. If you don't get an insight into the issue when making it smaller, you can then post the smaller project with just the issue here. This questions is too long to get most people to understand and reproduce.

Comment: I was expecting it'd be too large, maybe it'd help me to track the problem too. Thanks, I'll try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a workaround to this.

The thing is that the points that draw the polyline in the polyline `DefiningGeometry` are the `Start` and `End` points of each segment. Those points are binded to the `AnchorPoint` property of their respective thumbs.

When an entity moves the `AnchorPoint` property are programmatically updated like this...

```
private void UpdateAnchorPoint()
{
    Size size = RenderSize;
    Point ofs = new Point(size.Width / 2, size.Height / 2);
    AnchorPoint = this.TranslatePoint(ofs, ChartCustomControl.Instance.ChartCanvas);
}
```

... the anchor point changes, the start/end points changes, `PropertyChangedCallback` call `InvalidateMeasure` on the line and the line moves.

This work perfect when dragging the entities, but doesn't work when changing the entities location only one time through `Canvas.SetLeft` and `Canvas.SetTop`, which is what undo/redo commands does:

```
internal void AutomaticMoveTo(Point p)
        {
            Canvas.SetLeft(this, p.X);
            Canvas.SetTop(this, p.Y);
            UpdateAnchorPoint();
            CalculateSnapCoords();
        }
```

For some reason, when the entities's location are changed that way, the `PropertyChangedCallback` of start/end properties aren't called the first time(don't ask me, I have no idea why), therefore accumulating a "one step delay".

However, if I calculate the thumb center manually and just assign a newly created `Point` object...

```
public void AutomaticMoveUpdateAnchorPoint()
        {
            double x = Canvas.GetLeft(MyBorder);
            double y = Canvas.GetTop(MyBorder);
            switch (Name)
            {
                case "ThTop":
                    x += (MyBorder.BorderContent.ActualWidth * 0.5d) + (MyBorder.RootGrid.ColumnDefinitions[0].ActualWidth * 1.75d);
                    y += (MyBorder.RootGrid.RowDefinitions[0].ActualHeight * 0.5d);
                    break;
                case "ThBottom":
                    x += (MyBorder.BorderContent.ActualWidth * 0.5d) + (MyBorder.RootGrid.ColumnDefinitions[0].ActualWidth * 1.75d);
                    y += MyBorder.BorderContent.ActualHeight + (MyBorder.RootGrid.RowDefinitions[0].ActualHeight * 1.5d);
                    break;
                case "ThLeft":
                    x += (MyBorder.RootGrid.ColumnDefinitions[0].ActualWidth);
                    y += (MyBorder.BorderContent.ActualHeight * 0.5d) + (MyBorder.RootGrid.RowDefinitions[0].ActualHeight);
                    break;
                case "ThRight":
                    x += (MyBorder.RootGrid.ColumnDefinitions[1].ActualWidth) + (MyBorder.RootGrid.ColumnDefinitions[0].ActualWidth * 2.25d);
                    y += (MyBorder.BorderContent.ActualHeight * 0.5d) + (MyBorder.RootGrid.RowDefinitions[0].ActualHeight);
                    break;
            }

            AnchorPoint = new Point(x, y);
        }
```

...it works perfect again. Bindings work correctly again and `PropertyChangedCallback` are being called normally again.

I don't know why this is happening. The bindings are standard `TwoWay`, `UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged`, and I understand that the the initial `TranslatePoint` line creates a new `Point` object too. Maybe it's not reflecting the canvas changes? I don't know, I don't see why this should happen, but well, I have the workaround, I use the new method and all goes ok.

I'll leave this here in case someone can use it or even found a reason to this.